# Why path drawn on scaled GLES20RecordingCanvas and simple Canvas has different qualities?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-graphics

Path drawn on scaled `GLES20RecordingCanvas` has quality as if it was drawn unscaled in bitmap and then up-scaled.

In contrast, if I create `Canvas` with backing bitmap and then apply the same scaling transformations to `Canvas` object I get much superior bitmap.

[image]
Here both circles are drawn with `Path.addCircle` and using `Canvas.scale`. Upper circle is drawn with scaled `GLES20RecordingCanvas` and lower is drawn with scaled simple `Canvas` with backing bitmap.

Some code:

```
public class TestPathRenderer extends View {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        float distortedWidth = getDistortedWidth();
        float distortedHeight = getDistortedHeight();

        path.reset();
        path.addCircle(distortedWidth/2f, distortedHeight/2f, Math.min(distortedWidth/2f, distortedHeight/2f), Path.Direction.CW);

        bitmap = assembleNewBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        switch (renderMode) {
            case RENDER_MODE_WO_BITMAP:
                drawOnCanvas(canvas);
                break;
            case RENDER_MODE_WITH_BITMAP:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Undefined render mode: " + renderMode);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap assembleNewBitmap(int w, int h) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawOnCanvas(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private void drawOnCanvas(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(DISTORTION_FACTOR, DISTORTION_FACTOR);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

[Full example](https://github.com/vganin/path-draw-test)

I can't understand the quality difference with these two cases. For me it seems that they have to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poor quality during scaling is a limitation of Hardware Acceleration according to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#scaling).

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your question, I decided to check out the source code of the `GLES20RecordingCanvas` class. And here's what I found out:

`GLES20RecordingCanvas` extends from `GLES20Canvas` which extends from `HardwareCanvas`. This `HardwareCanvas` class extends from `Canvas`. But the main difference I noticed is that it overrides the `isHardwareAcceleratedMethod()` returning true.

So my assumption is that the `GLES20RecordingCanvas` renders the bitmap with Hardware Acceleration while Canvas doesn't. And this is probably why you get less quality with the `GLES20RecorgingCanvas`.

Comment: You can check the value of `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` for both `Canvas` and `GLES20RecordingCanvas`

Comment: Question claims it's the other way around. If it were the opposite it's would have make perfect sense, since openGL using vertices to represent shapes, and bitmap is using pixels

Comment: @YoniGross Thank you. I misunderstood. Just edited my answer